# Contar repeticiones de enteros C++, Array

Tags: c++, array

Buenas, el ejercicio dice lo siguiente

"Diseñar un algoritmo que acepte de teclado un número natural n y cuente el número de veces que se repite cada dígito dentro del mismo"

Se que no he colgado mi código, pero es que no se por donde empezar, es decir, si a cada elemento del array le meto mas de varios dígitos no se como realizar el recuento de cada dígito, mas bien el problema lo tengo en separar el valor del array en dígitos.

Sí he intentado resolverlo usando lápiz y papel. He desarrollado el siguiente algoritmo:

1.- Escribe las cifras del 0 al 9 de arriba a abajo.
2.- Escribe el número a procesar de izquierda a derecha. Pon el dedo en la cifra de la izquierda.
3.- Añade un palito a la cifra vertical que se corresponde con la cifra donde está el dedo.
4.- Mueve el dedo una cifra a la derecha.
5.- Si el dedo está sobre una cifra ve al paso 3.
6.- Problema resuelto, los palitos indican cuantas veces aparece cada cifra.

He aquí un dibujo con mi algoritmo en acción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta pregunta es una copia mejorada de una que en tiempos hizo [Skydez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/27569/skydez) y que fue borrada.

Comment: deberias leer un libro de c++

Comment: Me parece una idea excelente @RenatoA. ¿Cual recomiendas? Por favor escribe [aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1811/propuesta-lista-de-libros-de-c-en-la-etiqueta) tu respuesta.

Comment: Antionio no quiero participar en ese post, ya que limitan los libros a solo lenguaje español

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te piden que proceses un número introducido por teclado... en este caso se puede asumir que únicamnte se va a introducir un número y esto nos permite tomar atajos: ¿Qué tal si en vez de leer el dato como un número y luego separar sus dígitos no leemos el número caracter a caracter? Con este nuevo planteamiento quedan algoritmos más sencillos.

Puedes optar por usar un array de tamaño fijo. El número de elementos coincide con el rango de valores a controlar. La idea es acumular en dicho array el número de apariciones de cada número. En este caso el rango de valores es 10 (números del 0 al 9).

La idea es ir leyendo dígito a dígito y sumar uno en la posición que le corresponda a dicho dígito:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int contador[10] = {0};

  char c;
  while( std::cin >> c && c != '\n' )
    contador[c-'0']++;

  for ( int i=0; i<10; ++i )
    std::cout << "La cifra " << i << " aparece " << contador[i] << " veces.\n";
}
```

Claro que si el código admite el estándar C++11 o superior se puede usar la clase `array` para poder usar iteradores y no tener que recordar el rango de valores:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main()
{
  std::array<int,10> contador = {0};

  char c;
  while( std::cin >> c && c != '\n' )
    contador[c-'0']++;

  for ( size_t i=0; i<contador.size(); ++i )
    std::cout << "La cifra " << i << " aparece " << contador[i] << " veces.\n";
}
```

Si el rango de valores fuese más amplio podría tener sentido utilizar un mapa. La ventaja de usar un mapa es que si una parte importante del rango no se usa el ahorro de memoria puede ser considerable.

Nota en el siguiente ejemplo como los dígitos que no se encuentren en el número no figuran en el resultado:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
  std::map<char,int> contador;

  char c;
  while( std::cin >> c && c != '\n' )
    contador[c]++;

  for ( auto& pair : contador )
    std::cout << "La cifra " << pair.first << " aparece " << pair.second << " veces.\n";
}
```

Otra ventaja de esta solución es que nos ahorramos la conversión `char->int`.

Por supuesto se podrían mostrar también los dígitos sin ocurrencias... a cambio el código se complicaría muy ligeramente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
  std::map<char,int> contador;

  char c;
  while( std::cin >> c && c != '\n' )
    contador[c]++;

  for ( char c = '0'; c <= '9'; ++c )
    std::cout << "La cifra " << c << " aparece " << contador[c] << " veces.\n";
}
```

Una mejora a estas dos últimas soluciones pasaría por usar `std::unordered_map`. Este contenedor daría mejores tiempos de respuesta si el rango de valores a mapear fuese elevado (varios miles). No es el caso así que no veo necesidad de extender más la respuesta. Simplemente quería dejar constancia de la existencia de esta tercera solución.

Answer (score 5):

Primero un programa que lee un número natural y lo imprime en pantalla :

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned int n;  // Variable de números no negativos
    std::cin >> n;   // Lee un número de teclado y lo almacena en n.
    std::cout << n;  // Imprime el número dentro de la variable n
    std::cout << std::endl; // Imprime salto de línea
    return 0;
}
```

Con eso ya sabes cómo leer un número de teclado.

Ahora un programa que imprime una a una las cifras de un número natural. Desde la más significativa a la menos significativa.
La última cifra de ún numero siempre es el resto de dividir ese número por 10. Esta operación en C++ se llama módulo y la hace el operador `%`.
Una vez imprimimos esa cifra nos quedamos con las superiores dividiendo por 10.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned int n = 19383;  // Variable de números no negativos con un valor
    do {
        int resto = n %10; // La última cifra
        std::cout << resto << std::endl; // La imprimimos con salto de línea
        n = n / 10; // Esto es una división entera
    } while ( n>0 ); // Cuando el número se queda a 0 es que ya no hay más cifras.
    return 0;
}
```

Con eso ya sabes cómo dividir un número en cifras.
Ya solo te falta contar cuántas veces aparece cada cifra.

Puedes usar un array de diez elementos para contar cada una de las diez cifras.

```
int cuentaCifra[0];
```

El cual debieras inicializar a 0.

```
for ( int i=0; i<10; ++i )
  cuentaCifra[i] = 0;
```

Y puedes imprimir tal que así :

```
for ( int i=0; i<10; ++i )
  std::cout << "La cifra " << i << " aparece " << cuentaCifra[i] << " veces." << std::endl;
```

Si te encuentras con la cifra `n` y quieres contabilizarla debes sumar uno a `cuentaCifra[n]`:

```
++cuentaCifra[n]
```

Junta todo lo que has aprendido anteriormente de una forma apropiada y tendrás la solución a tu ejercicio.

Answer (score 3):

No hace falta ninguna característica propia de C++, así que me limitaré a C (de paso, diferencio mi respuesta de las anteriores, aportando algo nuevo).

Para poder leer un número del teclado, utilizaremos `scanf()`. Esta función permite guardar en una variable entera un número tomado del teclado, como por ejemplo: `int num; scanf( "%d", &num )`. Es importante recordar poner un ampersand delante de la variable, pues será modificada dentro de `scanf()`. El contrario de `scanf()` es `printf()`, que permite visualizar un valor por consola. Ambas funciones aceptar una cadena de caracteres para saber el formato del valor a mostrar o a pedir por teclado, como primer parámetro. `%d` representa a un número entero, equivalente al tipo `int`.

Para guardar los resultados, necesitamos una estructura de datos que nos permita almacenar el resultado del conteo para cada cifra. Necesitaremos poder preguntar: ¿para 5?, y que nos devuelva: 1 vez (o las que sean). También necesitampos poder decirle: "incrementa el conteo en 1 para 5". Es decir, necesitamos poder asociar un valor entero (el conteo), con otro valor entero (un dígito del 0 al 9). En C++ es posible utilizar un `map<>`, pero en el caso específico de asociar un valor entero con otro valor entero, podemos utilizar un simple vector, un array primitivo. Si creamos: `int digitos[10]`, entonces tendremos 10 valores enteros para guardar el conteo de caracteres: uno en la posición 0, otro en la posición 1... así, la posición en el vector (el índice) representa los dígitos, mientras el valor de la posición, el conteo. Eso sí, tendremos que inicializar cada posición del vector a cero antes de utilizarlo.

Finalmente, necesitamos poder acceder a cada cifra del número que haya introducido el usuario por teclado. Una forma de hacer esto es convertir el número a cadena de caracteres, y entonces acceder a cada posición y contabilizarla. Pero esto implica reservar memoria, cuando podemos hacer lo mismo con unos cálculos simples: supongamos que tenemos el número 482. Si dividimos el número entre 10, nos queda 48. El resto será 2. Si dividimos 48 entre 10, el resultado es 4, mientras el resto es 8. Si volvemos a dividir el número entre 10, el resultado es 0, el resto es 4. Con los restos de las divisiones, hemos "recorrido" cada cifra del número, eso sí, en sentido inverso, aunque para contar las apariciones de cada cifra eso da igual. Lo único a tener en cuenta es que el número debe ser positivo, así que será necesario llamar a `abs()`.

Eso sí, para poder hacer todo esto es necesario emplear bucles, que permiten repetir la ejecución de un cuerpo de instrucciones varias veces. `for()` se emplea cuando previamente se conoce el número de veces que tendrán que ejecutarse ese cuerpo de instrucciones. `while()` se emplea cuando el número de veces a repetir ese código no se conoce, por lo que se acompaña de una condición, y el cuerpo de instrucciones se ejecutará mientras dicha condición se cumpla (devuelva `true`).

```
void cuenta_ocurrencias_digitos(int n, int digitos[])
{
    // Inicializa
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        digitos[ i ] = 0;
    }

    // Cuenta las ocurrencias
    n = abs( n );
    while( n > 0 ) {
        digitos[ n % 10 ] += 1;
        n /= 10;
    }
}
```

La función anterior inicializa el vector `digitos`, y después descompone el número en cifras, incrementando en uno la posición en el vector para cada una de ellas.

Ya solo queda mostrar los resultados. Los únicos resultados relevantes son el conteo de cifras cuando dicho conteo es superior a cero, como se ve en la siguiente función.

```
void muestra_resultado(int n, int digitos[])
{
    printf( "\nPara: %d\n", n );
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        if ( digitos[ i ] > 0 ) {
            printf( "%d aparece %d veces.\n", i, digitos[ i ] );
        }
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}
```

Espero que todo esto te ayude. Tienes el [código completo en IDEOne](http://ideone.com/4zaEPA).